# At what point does up voting become serial?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, up-votes

I think that some of my up votes here may have been reversed for being serial? I want to be sure not to break any rules whilst achieving the badge for up voting. That maybe how I got suspension in Physics.SE for voter fraud?  Is there a definition on serial up voting and does it differ than down votes?

P.S. I very rarely down vote.

Comment: (approx) 10 in a day seems to trigger the automatic reversal script (which in turn flags the moderators to look at your voting patterns). Mods can also see who you've voted for, so if you're repeatedly upvoting *a particular individual* in a way that seems hinky, that might earn you a suspension

Comment: @Valorum I'm sure it did! All I got as far as a warning or reprimand was a vague I had committed voting fraud but didn't say when and where. I had no idea up voting incorrectly could equal a suspension. Wow. That should be an answer somewhere. I should be able to up vote without consequence.

Comment: Slightly related: if another user is in the process of closing one of your questions, or helping you reopen it, and (presumably by coincidence) you up vote ten of their posts in two minutes on another SE site, it can look bad for both you and the other user. Please at least consider the other user's request to not *up vote en masse* their posts. In this case it doesn't matter what you were "trying to do" as much as matters what it *could look like you are trying to do* to others.

Comment: A suspension for vote fraud means you must have done something much worse than serial voting!

Comment: @RoryAlsop I didn't!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exact definition is kept secret, but basically, a [serial voting reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) happens when the StackExchange software thinks you've been voting based on who provided the questions/answers, rather than based on what those posts say.

If you're trying to get one of the voting badges, that means you should avoid finding things to vote on from a user's profile, or from a single tag.  Instead, use the main question list, or wander through the "related questions" links from an interesting question.

Comment: At a guess?  I've seen someone report a serial voting reversal after three votes, so two votes in a single day should be safe under all circumstances.  You can probably go well above that, if your votes on a single user are mixed in with thirty or forty votes on other users.

Comment: @Muze The PSE mods/CMs probably watched you. Although mods have no access to induvidual votes, they have some tools to detect voting irregularities, whose details they don't say. They have at least a feature to know, who voted an induvidual at most. If they have hyphotesis that X and Y accounts are cross-voting eachother, they can validate it. They can also ask the CMs. The CMs can see induvidual votes, except the ones to their own posts. All the CMs are SE employee.

Comment: I'm aware of a set of targeted votes that were reversed even though there were fewer than three votes on any particular day. Vote for content, not for people.